# ansible nested variable lookup refactoring

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm using this kind of ansible lookup, in order to load the content of a file into a variable :

```
- name: Prepare ignition for worker nodes
  set_fact:
    custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', './files/ignition/{{ oc_cluster_name }}/worker.ign') | b64encode  }}"
  when: item.name.startswith('worker')
```

I know that we should avoid using nested variables (moustaches don't stack, right ?). This code is working indeed, but I'm not sure it's the correct way to write this.

Is there another way to do it ? I used to write in two separate "set_fact" blocks, which works as well, but it's not better (using temporary vars) :

```
- name: Prepare ignition for worker nodes
  block:
    - name: locate file for worker node
      set_fact:
        ignition_file: "./files/ignition/{{ oc_cluster_name }}/worker.ign"

    - name: load file into fact for worker node
      set_fact:
        custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', ignition_file) | b64encode  }}"
   when: item.name.startswith('worker')
```

What do you think ?

I'm trying to write nice code with best practices : using no temporary variable and respecting the way to nest interpolation of variables

Comment: [edit] the question and make it [mre]. As a hint, try to incorporate the logic `item.name.startswith('worker')` into the code below. It seems like an iteration.

Comment: The correct way to write `custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', './files/ignition/{{ oc_cluster_name }}/worker.ign') | b64encode  }}"` without stacking moustaches is to do a simple concatenation: 
`custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', './files/ignition/' ~ oc_cluster_name ~ '/worker.ign') | b64encode  }}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moustaches shouldn't be stacked because it's not necessary to do so. You're already in a Jinja expression so you just access variables by name without wrapping them in more delimiters.

```yaml
- name: Prepare ignition for worker nodes
  set_fact:
    # Relative paths are looked for in `files/` first, so there's no need to specify it
    custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', 'ignition/' ~ oc_cluster_name ~ '/worker.ign') | b64encode }}"
  when: item.name.startswith('worker')
```

You can also use a temporary variable without a separate `set_fact`, which can be helpful for breaking up complex expressions:

```yaml
- name: Prepare ignition for worker nodes
  set_fact:
    custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', ignition_file) | b64encode  }}"
  vars:
    ignition_file: ignition/{{ oc_cluster_name }}/worker.ign
  when: item.name.startswith('worker')
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"Write nice code."***

A: Put the declarations into the [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). For example, into the *group_vars/all*

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── ignition
│       └── cluster1
│           └── worker.ign
├── group_vars
│   └── all
├── hosts
└── pb.yml

4 directories, 5 files
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
inventory = $PWD/hosts
remote_tmp = ~/.ansible/tmp
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

```bash
shell> cat files/ignition/cluster1/worker.ign 
test
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all 
oc_cluster_name: cluster1
ignition_file: "./files/ignition/{{ oc_cluster_name }}/worker.ign"
custom_attr: "{{ lookup('file', ignition_file)|b64encode  }}"
```

```ini
shell> cat hosts 
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: custom_attr|b64decode
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  custom_attr|b64decode: test

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```